# Server full ram but not show which process is use much RAM

Tags: centos7, hadoop, memory-leak

One of our Hadoop datanode with CentOS7 64 bit is using all of it's RAM, I tried to figure out which process is using so much RAM but couldn't. Please help me to check this please:

System: CentOS 7 64bit, with 64 GiB RAM

**HTOP on server:**
[Htop show that all memory is used:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sUlEm.png)

**PS to find which process is use much RAM** - see only 3 process use more than 10%, but total less than 50%:

```
~]# ps aux | awk '{print $4"\t"$11}' | sort | uniq -c | awk '{print $2" "$1" "$3}' | sort -nr|more
14.0 1 /zserver/java/jdk1.8.0_11-x64/bin/java
13.8 1 /zserver/java/jdk1.8.0_11-x64/bin/java
12.3 1 /zserver/java/jdk1.8.0_11-x64/bin/java
1.7 1 /zserver/java/jdk1.8.0_11-x64/bin/java
0.2 1 /opt/dell/srvadmin/sbin/dsm_om_connsvcd
0.1 1 /zserver/java/jdk1.8.0_11-x64/bin/java
%MEM 1 COMMAND
0.0 2 sshd:
0.0 2 sort
0.0 2 /opt/dell/srvadmin/sbin/dsm_sa_datamgrd
0.0 2 [ext4-unrsv-conv]
0.0 2 [ext4-rsv-conver]
0.0 2 /bin/bash
```

Memory Info:

```
~]# cat /proc/meminfo 
MemTotal:       65696732 kB
MemFree:          300744 kB
MemAvailable:     603864 kB
Buffers:             724 kB
Cached:           401512 kB
SwapCached:       661620 kB
Active:         25435684 kB
Inactive:        3525360 kB
Active(anon):   25367048 kB
Inactive(anon):  3362788 kB
Active(file):      68636 kB
Inactive(file):   162572 kB
Unevictable:           0 kB
Mlocked:               0 kB
SwapTotal:      14680056 kB
SwapFree:        6062316 kB
Dirty:              2464 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:      27894800 kB
Mapped:            25504 kB
Shmem:            173228 kB
Slab:             442388 kB
SReclaimable:     317624 kB
SUnreclaim:       124764 kB
KernelStack:       20272 kB
PageTables:        75916 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:    14680056 kB
Committed_AS:   34058880 kB
VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:      410120 kB
VmallocChunk:   34325729008 kB
HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
AnonHugePages:   1187840 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
DirectMap4k:      110288 kB
DirectMap2M:     3985408 kB
DirectMap1G:    65011712 kB
```

**vmstat -s**

```
~]# vmstat -s
     65696732 K total memory
     64522660 K used memory
     25454076 K active memory
      3453168 K inactive memory
       334916 K free memory
         1276 K buffer memory
       837880 K swap cache
     14680056 K total swap
      8610992 K used swap
      6069064 K free swap
   6298373517 non-nice user cpu ticks
         4033 nice user cpu ticks
    554662032 system cpu ticks
  40820968522 idle cpu ticks
    245079249 IO-wait cpu ticks
        34653 IRQ cpu ticks
     29684952 softirq cpu ticks
            0 stolen cpu ticks
 411523475646 pages paged in
 247562770289 pages paged out
     21705066 pages swapped in
     15439699 pages swapped out
   1995305583 interrupts
   3450539885 CPU context switches
   1440495600 boot time
    394260663 forks
```

**cat /proc/slabinfo**

```
slabinfo - version: 2.1
# name            <active_objs> <num_objs> <objsize> <objperslab> <pagesperslab> : tunables <limit> <batchcount> <sharedfactor> : slabdata <active_slabs> <num_slabs> <sharedavail>
xfs_icr                0      0    144   56    2 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata      0      0      0
xfs_ili            11686  11686    152   53    2 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata    221    221      0
xfs_inode         119224 119868   1024   32    8 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata   3920   3920      0
xfs_efd_item        4960   4960    400   40    4 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata    124    124      0
xfs_da_state        1608   1608    488   67    8 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata     24     24      0
xfs_btree_cur        936    936    208   39    2 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata     24     24      0
xfs_log_ticket     15180  15400    184   44    2 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata    350    350      0
fat_inode_cache      180    180    720   45    8 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata      4      4      0
fat_cache            102    102     40  102    1 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata      1      1      0
kvm_async_pf           0      0    136   60    2 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata      0      0      0
kvm_vcpu               0      0  16256    2    8 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata      0      0      0
kvm_mmu_page_header      0      0    168   48    2 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata      0      0      0
kcopyd_job             0      0   3312    9    8 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata      0      0      0
dm_uevent              0      0   2608   12    8 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata      0      0      0
dm_rq_target_io        0      0    424   38    4 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata      0      0      0
ext4_groupinfo_4k   3720   3720    136   60    2 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata     62     62      0
ext4_inode_cache    3894   6047   1048   31    8 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata    205    205      0
ext4_xattr            46     46     88   46    1 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata      1      1      0
ext4_free_data      9920  10240     64   64    1 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata    160    160      0
ext4_allocation_context   1536   1536    128   64    2 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata     24     24      0
ext4_io_end        12699  12699     80   51    1 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata    249    249      0
ext4_extent_status  25808  26520     40  102    1 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata    260    260      0
jbd2_journal_handle   2040   2040     48   85    1 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata     24     24      0
jbd2_journal_head   6552   6552    112   36    1 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata    182    182      0
jbd2_revoke_table_s    512    512     16  256    1 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata      2      2      0
jbd2_revoke_record_s   3072   3072     32  128    1 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata     24     24      0
scsi_cmd_cache      5976   6156    448   36    4 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata    171    171      0
UDPLITEv6              0      0   1152   28    8 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata      0      0      0
UDPv6                672    672   1152   28    8 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata     24     24      0
tw_sock_TCPv6       2816   3264    256   64    4 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata     51     51      0
TCPv6               1148   1280   2048   16    8 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata     80     80      0
cfq_queue          20230  20580    232   70    4 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata    294    294      0
bsg_cmd                0      0    312   52    4 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata      0      0      0
mqueue_inode_cache     36     36    896   36    8 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata      1      1      0
hugetlbfs_inode_cache     53     53    608   53    8 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata      1      1      0
configfs_dir_cache      0      0     88   46    1 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata      0      0      0
dquot               1536   1536    256   64    4 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata     24     24      0
kioctx                 0      0    576   56    8 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata      0      0      0
pid_namespace          0      0   2176   15    8 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata      0      0      0
posix_timers_cache      0      0    248   66    4 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata      0      0      0
UDP-Lite               0      0   1024   32    8 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata      0      0      0
ip_fib_trie          146    146     56   73    1 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata      2      2      0
RAW                  952    952    960   34    8 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata     28     28      0
UDP                  768    768   1024   32    8 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata     24     24      0
tw_sock_TCP        11904  12224    256   64    4 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata    191    191      0
TCP                 1385   1553   1920   17    8 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata     94     94      0
blkdev_queue         305    352   2016   16    8 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata     22     22      0
blkdev_requests    43216  43216    384   42    4 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata   1032   1032      0
blkdev_ioc          1248   1248    104   39    1 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata     32     32      0
fsnotify_event_holder   4080   4080     24  170    1 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata     24     24      0
fsnotify_event     18089  18428    120   68    2 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata    271    271      0
sock_inode_cache    7157   7548    640   51    8 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata    148    148      0
net_namespace          0      0   4224    7    8 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata      0      0      0
shmem_inode_cache   3600   3600    680   48    8 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata     75     75      0
Acpi-ParseExt     126896 126896     72   56    1 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata   2266   2266      0
Acpi-Namespace     12036  12036     40  102    1 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata    118    118      0
taskstats           1176   1176    328   49    4 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata     24     24      0
proc_inode_cache   10722  10961    656   49    8 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata    415    415      0
sigqueue            1275   1275    160   51    2 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata     25     25      0
bdev_cache           429    429    832   39    8 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata     11     11      0
sysfs_dir_cache    46944  46944    112   36    1 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata   1304   1304      0
inode_cache        16541  16732    592   55    8 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata    306    306      0
dentry             69396  69489    192   42    2 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata   1655   1655      0
iint_cache             0      0     80   51    1 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata      0      0      0
selinux_inode_security  15819  16524     80   51    1 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata    324    324      0
buffer_head        17377  21060    104   39    1 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata    540    540      0
vm_area_struct     11403  12654    216   37    2 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata    342    342      0
mm_struct            800    800   1600   20    8 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata     40     40      0
files_cache         1428   1428    640   51    8 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata     28     28      0
signal_cache        3180   3360   1152   28    8 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata    120    120      0
sighand_cache       1770   1803   2112   15    8 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata    123    123      0
task_xstate         6575   7106    832   39    8 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata    184    184      0
task_struct         1770   1805   2912   11    8 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata    165    165      0
anon_vma           11769  12288     64   64    1 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata    192    192      0
shared_policy_node  11730  11730     48   85    1 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata    138    138      0
numa_policy          186    186    264   62    4 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata      3      3      0
radix_tree_node   158606 260645    584   56    8 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata   4664   4664      0
idr_layer_cache      743    780   2112   15    8 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata     52     52      0
dma-kmalloc-8192       0      0   8192    4    8 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata      0      0      0
dma-kmalloc-4096       0      0   4096    8    8 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata      0      0      0
dma-kmalloc-2048       0      0   2048   16    8 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata      0      0      0
dma-kmalloc-1024       0      0   1024   32    8 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata      0      0      0
dma-kmalloc-512        0      0    512   64    8 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata      0      0      0
dma-kmalloc-256        0      0    256   64    4 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata      0      0      0
dma-kmalloc-128        0      0    128   64    2 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata      0      0      0
dma-kmalloc-64         0      0     64   64    1 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata      0      0      0
dma-kmalloc-32         0      0     32  128    1 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata      0      0      0
dma-kmalloc-16         0      0     16  256    1 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata      0      0      0
dma-kmalloc-8          0      0      8  512    1 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata      0      0      0
dma-kmalloc-192        0      0    192   42    2 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata      0      0      0
dma-kmalloc-96         0      0     96   42    1 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata      0      0      0
kmalloc-8192         273    310   8192    4    8 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata     79     79      0
kmalloc-4096         862    897   4096    8    8 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata    113    113      0
kmalloc-2048        1696   1830   2048   16    8 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata    124    124      0
kmalloc-1024        5193   5440   1024   32    8 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata    170    170      0
kmalloc-512         9437  10232    512   64    8 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata    166    166      0
kmalloc-256         9572  13392    256   64    4 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata    210    210      0
kmalloc-192        13970  15078    192   42    2 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata    359    359      0
kmalloc-128        22042  24576    128   64    2 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata    384    384      0
kmalloc-96          4454   4620     96   42    1 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata    110    110      0
kmalloc-64         43106  51072     64   64    1 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata    798    798      0
kmalloc-32         19072  19072     32  128    1 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata    149    149      0
kmalloc-16         13312  13568     16  256    1 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata     53     53      0
kmalloc-8          16896  16896      8  512    1 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata     33     33      0
kmem_cache_node      682    704     64   64    1 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata     11     11      0
kmem_cache           576    576    256   64    4 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata      9      9      0
```

Have tried to drop the system cache, but the memory doesn't free up:

```
# sync; echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
# sync; echo 2 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
# sync; echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

**slabtop -o**

```
 Active / Total Objects (% used)    : 1244950 / 1358427 (91.6%)
 Active / Total Slabs (% used)      : 31188 / 31188 (100.0%)
 Active / Total Caches (% used)     : 77 / 106 (72.6%)
 Active / Total Size (% used)       : 473366.03K / 528796.00K (89.5%)
 Minimum / Average / Maximum Object : 0.01K / 0.39K / 15.88K

  OBJS ACTIVE  USE OBJ SIZE  SLABS OBJ/SLAB CACHE SIZE NAME                   
231616 169413  73%    0.57K   4143       56    132576K radix_tree_node        
203516 195136  95%    1.00K   8291       32    265312K xfs_inode              
126896 126896 100%    0.07K   2266       56      9064K Acpi-ParseExt          
101166  92953  91%    0.10K   2594       39     10376K buffer_head            
 96453  86834  90%    0.19K   2297       42     18376K dentry                 
 66044  62392  94%    0.38K   1574       42     25184K blkdev_requests        
 51072  45181  88%    0.06K    798       64      3192K kmalloc-64             
 46944  46944 100%    0.11K   1304       36      5216K sysfs_dir_cache        
 26520  25808  97%    0.04K    260      102      1040K ext4_extent_status     
 24704  23935  96%    0.12K    386       64      3088K kmalloc-128            
 20160  19810  98%    0.23K    288       70      4608K cfq_queue              
 19072  19072 100%    0.03K    149      128       596K kmalloc-32             
 18428  18089  98%    0.12K    271       68      2168K fsnotify_event         
 16896  16896 100%    0.01K     33      512       132K kmalloc-8              
 16732  16541  98%    0.58K    306       55      9792K inode_cache            
 16524  15819  95%    0.08K    324       51      1296K selinux_inode_security 
 15444  15224  98%    0.18K    351       44      2808K xfs_log_ticket         
 15036  14311  95%    0.19K    358       42      2864K kmalloc-192            
 14813  14813 100%    0.15K    280       53      2240K xfs_ili                
 14016  12421  88%    0.06K    219       64       876K anon_vma               
 13584  10797  79%    0.25K    213       64      3408K kmalloc-256            
 13568  13312  98%    0.02K     53      256       212K kmalloc-16             
 12950  12528  96%    0.21K    350       37      2800K vm_area_struct         
 12699  12699 100%    0.08K    249       51       996K ext4_io_end            
 12224  11904  97%    0.25K    191       64      3056K tw_sock_TCP            
 12036  12036 100%    0.04K    118      102       472K Acpi-Namespace         
 11730  11730 100%    0.05K    138       85       552K shared_policy_node     
 10736  10680  99%    0.50K    180       64      5760K kmalloc-512            
 10240   9920  96%    0.06K    160       64       640K ext4_free_data         
  8573   8531  99%    0.64K    189       49      6048K proc_inode_cache       
  7548   7157  94%    0.62K    148       51      4736K sock_inode_cache       
  7067   6574  93%    0.81K    183       39      5856K task_xstate            
  6552   6552 100%    0.11K    182       36       728K jbd2_journal_head      
  6372   6012  94%    0.44K    177       36      2832K scsi_cmd_cache         
  6047   3894  64%    1.02K    205       31      6560K ext4_inode_cache       
  5568   5165  92%    1.00K    174       32      5568K kmalloc-1024           
  4452   4171  93%    0.09K    106       42       424K kmalloc-96             
  4080   4080 100%    0.02K     24      170        96K fsnotify_event_holder  
  4010   3730  93%    0.39K    101       40      1616K xfs_efd_item           
  3720   3720 100%    0.13K     62       60       496K ext4_groupinfo_4k      
  3600   3600 100%    0.66K     75       48      2400K shmem_inode_cache      
  3360   3180  94%    1.12K    120       28      3840K signal_cache           
  3264   2816  86%    0.25K     51       64       816K tw_sock_TCPv6          
  3072   3072 100%    0.03K     24      128        96K jbd2_revoke_record_s   
  2040   2040 100%    0.05K     24       85        96K jbd2_journal_handle    
  1838   1702  92%    2.84K    168       11      5376K task_struct            
  1803   1770  98%    2.06K    123       15      3936K sighand_cache          
  1630   1540  94%    2.00K    108       16      3456K kmalloc-2048
```

Any idea please?

Thanks all.

Comment: Can you show the output of `top -o RES` ?

Comment: top -o RES  : show the same as htop do, @shodanshok  : [link] (https://s23.postimg.org/eaxpwpevv/top_mem.png)

Comment: can you post the output of `sysctl -a | grep -i huge`  and `hugeadm --pool-list` ?

Comment: @shodanshok : here is the result:  http://pastebin.com/EuEHCxqc

Comment: Is the server virtual or physical? Can you post the kernel boot command line (`cat /proc/cmdline`)?

Comment: @shodanshok:  It is physical server.` (~]# cat /proc/cmdline
BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-3.10.0-229.11.1.el7.x86_64 root=UUID=456cc3dc-c73e-4707-964a-2200c95be2c2 ro crashkernel=auto net.ifnames=0 biosdevname=0 rhgb quiet LANG=en_US.UTF-8 systemd.debug
)`

Comment: Can you show the output of `dmesg` and `cat /proc/iomem` ?

Comment: @shodanshok: my server had crashed and restarted, the memory is ok after reboot, thanks alot for your attention.

Answer (score 0):

Java is using 40% memory, those processes run inside the JVM and have different process scheduler

jps | grep JAVA_NAME | awk '{print $1}'

Also how much memory are you giving to Java, it could be claiming that memory on start up, I think it uses its own memory manager

Comment: Here is the output:

Comment: Result for: java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version | grep -iE 'HeapSize|PermSize|ThreadStackSize'
 is: 
http://pastebin.com/wZdaeFCE

Comment: Result for: jps | grep JAVA_NAME | awk '{print $1}'
http://pastebin.com/71cLJGGd

Comment: The command can be simplified to `jps | awk '/JAVA_NAME/{print $1}'`.